# Handle a 404 when networks shows a 200

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, jsonp

What is wrong with this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23458/):

```
function mainCtrl($scope, $http) {
  function loadData(){ $http.jsonp('http://www.pais.co.il/Lotto/Pages/last_Results.aspx?download=1')
                .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    console.log(data);
                });
        }
        loadData();
    };
```

I have a simple call to a URL. 
I can see in my network that it was a success (200).
But my the response is beeing catch in the error function:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting a 404 error. You are getting an invalid JS error.

You are making a JSONP request. The URL is returning CSV data, not JSONP.

You need to either:

1. Use a URL that returns JSONP
2. Use XMLHttpRequest instead of `<script>` (which is what `$http.jsonp` does behind the scenes) to load the data and ensure that the suitable Access-Control headers are set to give your JS permission to read the data
3. Fetch the data from your server instead

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about the 2nd possibility?

Comment: Use `$http()` instead of `$http.jsonp()` and see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS